# Trying to aggregate by mean and then trim outliers of observations based on the mean in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I'm trying to find the average value by item type, and then set a variable y that takes the value:

1. missing value if x = 0,
2. y = x.  Then round values that are too big or too small:
3. if x > 0, x > mu, then set y = mu
4. if x < 0, x < mu, then set y = mu

This is what I've tried, which doesn't produce the desired result below:

```
 tab2:([]items:`a`b`a`a`b; x:-6 8 0 -3 5)
 tabsum: select mu:avg x by items from tab2;
 tab2: update y:x from tab2
 tab2: update y:mu from tab2 where x > 0 and x > mu / get error after running above step
 tab2: update y:mu from tab2 where x < 0 and x <= mu
```

Desired result:

```
 items  x   mu    y
     a -6 -3.0 -3.0
     b  8  6.5  6.5
     a  0 -3.0  NaN
     a -3 -3.0 -3.0
     b  5  6.5  5
```

Related to this data:

i) Is NaN the appropriate type for missing values in kdb? (`NA` is different to `NaN` or `NULL` in R for example).  I'm guessing so based on what I've read so far.

ii) Is there more efficient code to get the mu column inside `tab2`?  Making another table and merging I'm guessing isn't efficient (still learning basics of kdb)

iii) 
If I just run

```
tab2:([]items:`a`b`a`a`b; x:-6 8 0 -3 5)
     tabsum: select mu:avg x by items from tab2;
     tab2: update y:mu from tab2 where x > 0 and x > mu
```

I get:

```
  items  x   mu   y
1     a -6 -3.0 NaN
2     b  8  6.5 6.5
3     a  0 -3.0 NaN
4     a -3 -3.0 NaN
5     b  5  6.5 6.5
```

Line 5 doesn't make sense to me. Why is y = 6.5 if x < mu?  I expect y =5 for that row.   Clearly my understanding of what's going on is wrong.

iv) How can I get the desired result (the code I've posted doesn't work properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the prettiest solution, but seems to fit your criteria. I'm using a vector conditional `?` to set the value of y:

```
q)show tab3: update y:?[((x>0) and x>mu) or ((x<0) and x<=mu);mu;x] from update mu:avg x by items from tab2
items x  mu  y  
----------------
a     -6 -3  -3 
b     8  6.5 6.5
a     0  -3  0  
a     -3 -3  -3 
b     5  6.5 5
```

And then replacing any `y=0` values with [null](http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB%3AQforMortals2/atoms#Infinities_and_NaN) `0n` (rather than NaN):

```
q)update y:0n from tab3 where y=0
items x  mu  y  
----------------
a     -6 -3  -3 
b     8  6.5 6.5
a     0  -3     
a     -3 -3  -3 
b     5  6.5 5
```

The unexpected result on your last line is down to order of execution; q code is executed right-to-left. So:

```
5>0 and 5>6.5
```

actually means:

```
5>(0 and 5>6.5)
```

which is:

```
5>0
```

which evaluates to true. To make the desired comparison, you need to use brackets:

```
q)(5>0) and 5>6.5
0b
```

There's a few reasons why your block of code doesn't work. On line 2, you don't update `tab2` with the `mu` column; you just create a new table. So consequently when you try to use `mu` on line 4, it doesn't exist (which will cause an error). On line 3 you set the values of `y` to be the same as `x`, but this also means the same *type* (integer). Then later when you try to reset `y` to a float value from `mu` you get a `'type` error.

Here's a block of code similar to yours that works:

```
q)tab2:([]items:`a`b`a`a`b; x:-6 8 0 -3 5)
q)tab2: update mu:avg x by items from tab2
q)tab2: update y:"f"$x from tab2
q)tab2: update y:mu from tab2 where (x>0) and (x> mu)
q)tab2: update y:mu from tab2 where (x<0) and (x<= mu)
q)tab2
items x  mu  y  
----------------
a     -6 -3  -3 
b     8  6.5 6.5
a     0  -3  0  
a     -3 -3  -3 
b     5  6.5 5
```

Comment: thanks for the link and the explanation! makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line:

`tab3: update y:?[abs[x]>abs[mu];mu;x] from (update mu:avg x by items from tab2) where x<>0`